# Disable RAID in custom kernel?

Tags: raid, linux-kernel, gentoo

I need a Gentoo 13 machine to test some software on the platform. I'm not a Gentoo regular, so I'm suffering their procedures. I noticed the kernel spends a couple of seconds booting due to RAID drivers:

```
[    5.372054] megaraid cmm: 2.20.2.7 (Release Date: Sun Jul 16 00:01:03 EST 2006)
[    5.373198] megaraid: 2.20.5.1 (Release Date: Thu Nov 16 15:32:35 EST 2006)
...
[    5.594109] raid6: sse2x1   gen() 12003 MB/s
[    5.611097] raid6: sse2x1   xor()  9410 MB/s
[    5.628121] raid6: sse2x2   gen() 13820 MB/s
[    5.645115] raid6: sse2x2   xor()  9796 MB/s
[    5.662144] raid6: sse2x4   gen() 15531 MB/s
[    5.679133] raid6: sse2x4   xor() 12439 MB/s
[    5.679133] raid6: using algorithm sse2x4 gen() 15531 MB/s
[    5.679133] raid6: .... xor() 12439 MB/s, rmw enabled
[    5.679133] raid6: using ssse3x2 recovery algorithm
...
[    6.496364] md: raid6 personality registered for level 6
[    6.496367] md: raid5 personality registered for level 5
[    6.496368] md: raid4 personality registered for level 4
...
```

In the demsg above, I configured and built the the kernel with (the build occurred with `genkernel all`):

```
CONFIG_BLK_DEV_MD=n
```

`CONFIG_BLK_DEV_MD` is supposed to be the root of the raid tree, but disabling it does not squash the various RAID drivers.

How do I disable RAID in a Gentoo kernel?

Comment: (If question is still relevant). Did you call `genkernel` with `--install` option? Your new kernel should end up in the `/boot` directory. If it is not happening, you are still using the old kernel. [Reference](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Genkernel#Changing_the_kernel)

Comment: The time lost for these tests and initializations are mere fractions of a second.